# On screen keyboard covers edit text in android studio

Tags: android

I'm working on an app in android studio.

I have an edit text and an image view inside a linear layout.
[image: Screenshot 1]

When you tap the edit text it's working good.
[image: Screenshot 2]

When I press the blue button on my keyboard at the bottom right it adds a new line and it's working fine.
[image: Screenshot 3]

When you go back up a line the on screen keyboard covers the edit text that is below text cursor.
[image: Screenshot 4]

I want the edit text to always stay above the on screen keyboard.
This image is what it looks like now and a fake image of what I want it to look like.
[image]

Is there something you can add in the xml file to fix this?

I can't find anything to fix this problem.

Answer (score 2):

use `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|adjustResize"` on the Activity tag in your AndroidManifest.

Wrap the layout in a ScrollView

Comment: This didn't fix it.