# How do you add windowSoftInputMode to one item

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

I want to add android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" only to recycler view.

When I add it into the manifest file it adds it to everything which I don't want.

When I add the line of code in the recycler view it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use below code, don't need to define anything in AndroidManifest file.

```
 (recyclerView.getLayoutManager() as LinearLayoutManager).stackFromEnd = true
```

Comment: You fixed this problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71723623/on-screen-keyboard-covers-edit-text-in-android-studio

Answer (score 1):

You can try this. Replace the viewItem with your view

In Java

```
viewItem.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN)
```

In Kotlin

```
viewItem.window!!.setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN)
```